# How do you get into TARDIS on minecraft with Dalek mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have the Dalek mod installed with forge on v 1.7.10 and it's all working fine but I can't get into the TARDISes!

I've tried holding a TARDIS key and right clicking but they just don't open. I've tried all the different TARDISes too.

(Tried sonic screwdriver too)

I've got in once or twice but it seems random.

Comment: Did you build, or spawn the TARDIS? Sometimes simply spawning items from mods can cause issues like this, and need to instead be made to work propoerly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are playing on 1.7 then you need to right click on the bottom portion of the Tardis with the Tardis key and walk in, else if you are in 1.8 then do the same, however without the key